# cypher match where each collection element IN another collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In cypher id like to return all paths containing only a known set of valid relationship names using something like

```
MATCH (i:VALID_RELATIONSHIPS), p=(n:MY_DOMAIN)-[rels*1..5]-(m) 
WHERE n.NAME='start_node' AND 
      ALL(t in rels WHERE type(t) IN extract(x IN i | x.RELATIONSHIP_NAME) ) 
RETURN nodes(p);
```

so `ALL t IN rels` should be contained in the collection of `VALID_RELATIONSHIPS`

however this returns an exception `i already defined with conflicting node type collection<any>`

Am I misunderstanding something here? The algorithm should loop through all `rels` (which I assume is a collection) in the path, and for each one; check that the type() is contained in the valid relationships collection `i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is of type Node: `i`

Why don't you pass in the valid relationship names as a parameter?

```
MATCH p=(n:MY_DOMAIN)-[rels*1..5]-(m) 
WHERE n.NAME='start_node' AND 
      ALL(t in rels WHERE type(t) IN {valid_rel_names} ) 
RETURN nodes(p);
```

Otherwise you have to aggregate your i's into a collection first

```
MATCH (i:VALID_RELATIONSHIPS)
WITH collect(i) as valid_rels
MATCH p=(n:MY_DOMAIN)-[rels*1..5]-(m) 
WHERE n.NAME='start_node' AND 
      ALL(t in rels WHERE type(t) IN extract(x IN valid_rels | x.RELATIONSHIP_NAME) ) 
RETURN nodes(p);
```

or already extract the rels upfront

```
MATCH (i:VALID_RELATIONSHIPS)
WITH collect(i.RELATIONSHIP_NAME) as valid_rel_names
MATCH p=(n:MY_DOMAIN)-[rels*1..5]-(m) 
WHERE n.NAME='start_node' AND 
      ALL(t in rels WHERE type(t) IN valid_rel_names ) 
RETURN nodes(p);
```

Comment: Great thanks Michael.  So it seems that my assumption that i was a collection was totally incorrect.  So why is rels a collection and i is not?